# User sessions with username and login

Tags: java, database, sockets, ssl

I'm in the process of writing a server/client application. Clients connect to the server via one way SSL through an SSL Socket. The server is connected to a database via JDBC. This database will hold all kinds of data, including usernames (Encrypted with AES) and passwords (Hashed with BCrypt).

At the moment, the client simply connects through SSL, but no usernames or passwords are involved. This is where my planning question comes in.

The client is a desktop application, and ideally I would like to allow the users to remember their credentials locally, so every time they start the client it will connect to the server automatically with no user input. What would be the safest way of storing the credentials locally? AES and Hash again? If so, when transmitting the credentials over the socket, should I be decrypting client side and transmitting in plain (SSL) text? (This sounds shady to me, but it might be my inexperience).

On the server side of things (It uses a cachedthreadpool for multiple connections), I will be doing quite a lot of different functions depending on what the client requests (It is an anorexically thin client). This can be anything from database data retrieval and relay, complex simulations and returning results, and whiteboard functionality for different users to share information. Ideally I would like the server to keep a tab on who is logged in (To be able to broadcast data for the whiteboard function for example). I guess it could be considered a session management functionality. I am a bit lost as to how to do this, as all the documentation I've read closes the socket after each transaction, so there is no way to send out broadcast information.

I understand this might be a very broad question, but now that the server and client are talking to eachother I want to make sure the protocol they speak is properly planned.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you encrypt and decrypt the password locally, where will you keep the key? Whatch out for not opening the System to replay-attacks.

Comment: Those were exactly my thoughts, how is it normally done? I'm sure loads of applications have some sort of local password storage. Would the safest be making the users type in their credentials every time?

Comment: I guess that depends on how picky you are with Password creation :) But seriously - there are loads of possibilities. And I know not nearly enough about that to suggest one. Hence only comment, no answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Hash after AES. Just make sure you vary the key. One way to do this is to use the user's own password or combination of userid and password as the key. This way the result will differ for each user. Also make sure you store the result using the Java property 'user.home'. This will ensure that only the user and administrators will be able to access the location that the encrypted password is stored in.

To keep tabs on the user, don't close the socket after each transaction. Store the socket in a Map so it can easily be retrieved for broadcasting as well has direct messaging. You just have to make sure socket communication occurs on 1 thread per socket. You also need to be able to terminate a socket if you lose the connection, since the user could just shutdown the app without notifying the server.

Alternatively you could use java.nio and channels to perform these operations in a single thread since nio can be configured to be non-blocking.

With the powerful CPUs we have these days many consider a threaded approach more performant and scalable than using channels.